# ContentLoadException was unhandled Cannot find ContentTypeReader WindowsGame1.LevelContentReader, ContentImporter

Tags: c#, xna

I have this runtime error and I just don't understand what is causing it. I get no errors during the build. My code is in 2 sections: a game program and a contentprocessor that the main is referencing.

The full error is:

> *ContentLoadException was unhandled:  Cannot find ContentTypeReader WindowsGame1.LevelContentReader, ContentImporter*

Here is the main game:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace WindowsGame1
{

public class LevelContentReader : ContentTypeReader<Level>
{
    protected override Level Read(ContentReader input, Level existingInstance)
    {
        Level level = new Level();
        level.Background = input.ReadObject<Texture2D>();
        int count = input.ReadInt32();
        level.LevelObjects = new List<MyLevelObject>(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            MyLevelObject obj = new MyLevelObject();
            obj.model = input.ReadObject<Model>();
            obj.Position = input.ReadVector3();
            obj.Rotation = input.ReadVector3();
            level.LevelObjects.Add(obj);
        }
        return level;
    }

}

public class MyLevelObject
{
    public Model model;
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Vector3 Rotation;
}

public class Level
{
    public List<MyLevelObject> LevelObjects;
    public Texture2D Background;
}



public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Level mylevel;
    Matrix view;
    Matrix proj;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 10, 150), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
        proj = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
        mylevel = Content.Load<Level>("mylevel2");

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(mylevel.Background, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        foreach (MyLevelObject myObject in mylevel.LevelObjects)
        {
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in myObject.model.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                }
            }
            myObject.model.Draw(Matrix.CreateTranslation(myObject.Position) * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(myObject.Rotation.X, myObject.Rotation.Y, myObject.Rotation.Z), view, proj);
        }
        // TODO: Add your drawing code here

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

And here is my contentprocessor. The main game has a reference to this, as well as my content:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Compiler;

using TInput = System.String;
using TOutput = System.String;

namespace ContentImporter
{

[ContentTypeWriter]
public class LevelContentWriter : ContentTypeWriter<Level>
{
    public override string GetRuntimeReader(TargetPlatform targetPlatform)
    {
        return "WindowsGame1.LevelContentReader, ContentImporter";
    }
    public override string GetRuntimeType(TargetPlatform targetPlatform)
    {
        return "ContentImporter.Level, ContentImporter";
    }
    protected override void Write(ContentWriter output, Level value)
    {
        output.WriteObject<TextureContent>(value.Background);
        output.Write(value.LevelObjects.Count);
        foreach (MyLevelObject obj in value.LevelObjects)
        {
            output.WriteObject<ModelContent>(obj.Model);
            output.Write(obj.Position);
            output.Write(obj.Rotation);
        }
    }
}

[ContentProcessor(DisplayName = "MyLevelProcessor")]
public class ContentProcessor1 : ContentProcessor<Level, Level>
{
    public override Level Process(Level input, ContentProcessorContext context)
    {
        Level level = new Level();
        level.LevelObjects = new List<MyLevelObject>();
        //Process the input, we'll need to create the texture that is specified
        ExternalReference<TextureContent> backgroundReference = new ExternalReference<TextureContent>(input.BackgroundFileName);
        level.Background = context.BuildAndLoadAsset<TextureContent, TextureContent>(backgroundReference, "TextureProcessor");
        foreach (MyLevelObject obj in input.LevelObjects)
        {
            MyLevelObject newobj = new MyLevelObject();
            newobj.Position = obj.Position;
            newobj.Rotation = obj.Rotation;
            ExternalReference<NodeContent> modelReference = new ExternalReference<NodeContent>(obj.ModelFileName);
            newobj.Model = context.BuildAndLoadAsset<NodeContent, ModelContent>(modelReference, "ModelProcessor");
            level.LevelObjects.Add(newobj);
        }
        return level;
    }

}

[ContentImporter(".mylevel", DisplayName = "My Level Importer", DefaultProcessor = "MyLevelProcessor")]
public class MyContentImporter : ContentImporter<Level>
{
    public override Level Import(string filename, ContentImporterContext context)
    {
        Level level = new Level();
        level.LevelObjects = new List<MyLevelObject>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filename)))
        {
            level.BackgroundFileName = GetAbsolutePath(filename, reader.ReadLine());
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            MyLevelObject info = new MyLevelObject();
            info.ModelFileName = GetAbsolutePath(filename, reader.ReadLine());
            string[] floats = reader.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            info.Position = new Vector3(float.Parse(floats[0]), float.Parse(floats[1]), float.Parse(floats[2]));
            info.Rotation = new Vector3(float.Parse(floats[3]), float.Parse(floats[4]), float.Parse(floats[5]));
            level.LevelObjects.Add(info);
        }
    }
        return level;
    }
    private string GetAbsolutePath(string input, string file)
    {
        return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(input), file);
    }
}

public class MyLevelObject
{
    public ModelContent Model;
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Vector3 Rotation;
    public string ModelFileName;
}
public class Level
{
    public List<MyLevelObject> LevelObjects;
    public TextureContent Background;
    public string BackgroundFileName;
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated in this matter because the book I am using mostly assumes that you are close to an expert in C# and it teaches all the nitty gritty behind XNA, instead of game concepts. It offers no troubleshooting in any form. The book is XNA Game Studio 4.0 Programming by Tom Miller and Dean Johnson.

BTW If you need more info than what I posted, I'll be glad to provide.

Comment: where exactly is the exception thrown?

Comment: It is thrown after is builds successfully. I would imagine it can't find the reader or something but it is in there where the book tells me. But it does build successfully

Comment: I meant, what line in your code throws this exception, i.e. can you post a stack trace?